# How to format a JavaScript string with replaceAll using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, formatting, replaceall

I am trying to format a kind of a board game notation which consists of tabs and spaces.
The original string is looking like this:

```text
1.    \td11-d9    \te7-e10    \n2.    \ta8-c8    \tg7-g10xf10    \n3.    \th11-h9    \tf7-i7
```

I used this replace method to clean up all of the tabs and new lines

```js
string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replaceAll('. ', '.');
```

So, after that the string is looking like this:

```text
1.d11-d9 e7-e10 2.a8-c8 g7-g10xf10 3.h11-h9 f7-i7
```

However, I want to add more space before the number with the dot. So, the string must look like this with 3 spaces before the number of the move (the number with the dot):

```text
1.d11-d9 e7-e10   2.a8-c8 g7-g10xf10   3.h11-h9 f7-i7
```

Can I also make all of these operations with a one line code or just one JavaScript method?

Comment: Maybe ``string.replace(/[^\S\n]+(?:\n(\d+\.))?/g, (_,x) => x ? `   ${x}` : " ").replaceAll('. ', '.')``

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do this in a single `.replace` call:

```js
const s = "1.    \td11-d9    \te7-e10    \n2.    \ta8-c8    \tg7-g10xf10    \n3.    \th11-h9    \tf7-i7    ";

var r = s.replace(/([.\s])\s*\t|\s+$|\n(?=\d\.)/g, '$1');

console.log(r);

//=> "1.d11-d9 e7-e10    2.a8-c8 g7-g10xf10    3.h11-h9 f7-i7"
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `([.\s])\s*\t`: Match dot or a whitespace and capture in group #1 followed by 0+ whitespaces followed by a tab. We will put back this replacement using `$1`
- `|`: OR
- `\s+$`: Match 1+ whitespaces before end
- `|`: OR
- `\n(?=\d\.)`: Match `\n` if it is followed by a digit and a dot

Comment: This answer is missing the single space required by the OP.  For example `1.d11-d9e7-e10` should be `1.d11-d9 e7-e10`

Comment: @MarkBaijens: You are right, I overlooked that. I have fixed that in my recent edit now.

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. Thanks! It added 4 spaces between the moves instead of 3 but it is OK like that.

Comment: Happy to note that it worked out, [you may mark an answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242)

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookahead with `(?=[1-9])` and `(?=[a-z])` to check if the number add two spaces, and if a letter just add one space.

```js
const string = `1.    \td11-d9    \te7-e10    \n2.    \ta8-c8    \tg7-g10xf10    \n3.    \th11-h9    \tf7-i7`

const result = string.replace(/\s+(?=[a-z])/gi, ' ').replace(/\s+(?=[1-9])/gi, '  ').replaceAll('. ', '.');

console.log(result)
```